# How can I confirm what type of encryption a video is using?

Tags: video, encryption, http-live-streaming

I've been tasked with confirming a video from our platform is being served using HLS encryption in the browser. I haven't found an easy way to determine the video's encryption on the client side. How can I determine what encryption a video is using on the client?

Answer (score 0):

HLS only supports AES-128 for [encrypting media segments](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-6.2.3).

You should see an EXT-X-KEY tag in the playlist that identifies the encryption method and the URL of the key file.